# Dynamically adding attributes to __init__ method in python

Tags: python

Is there any way you can define a function that can add,at some later point in the program, new attributes to an already existing `__init__` method?  For example, below I created a Class for a Family Tree.  Each instance would create a root.

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
```

I want each new root instance to have the ability to have a specific number of children attributes: For example:

```
self.child1 = 'B'
self.child2 = 'C'
self.child3 = 'D'
```

Since every new root instance can have various number of children, how can I variably add new attributes to the `__init__` method?

Comment: how do you know how many children does an instance have? a new variable used when initalizing maybe?

Comment: Your wording is confusing and misleading. You are not adding to the `__init__` method, you are adding to the class instance. Consider rewording your question slightly to clear up this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible way to automate this is as follow:

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj, child_names=None):
        self.key = rootObj
        if child_names is not None:
            # child_names is a list of child attributes values
            for i, child in enumerate(child_names):
                setattr(self, 'child{0}'.format(i), child)
            setattr(self, 'child_nbr', len(child_names))

    def add_child(self, *child_names)
        for name in child_names:
            self.child_nbr += 1
            setattr(self, 'child{0}'.format(self.child_nbr), name)
```

usage:

```
>>> f=FamilyTree('Family1', ['B', 'C', 'D'])
>>> print(f.child1, f.child2, f.child3)
>>> i = 0
>>> while i < f.child_nbr:
>>>     print getattr(f, 'child{0}'.format(i+1))
>>> f.add_child('E')
>>> print(f.child4)
>>> f.add_child('F', 'G')
>>> print(f.child5, f.child6)
```

Comment: Thank you.  setattr is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what you really (should) want is a `list` of children:

```
class FamilyTree:

    def __init__(self, rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj
        self.children = []

    def add_children(*new_children)
        self.children.extend(new_children)
```

Now you can use the `add_children` method to add any number of children to the list at once, or you could simply directly access the `children` instance member list as well:

```
tree = FamilyTree("whatever a rootObj is...")

tree.add_children("Alice", "Bob", "Claudia", "Dave")
tree.children.append("Eva")
tree.children += ["Fred", "Gina", "Herbert"]

print(tree.children)
# Output: ["Alice", "Bob", "Claudia", "Dave", "Eva", "Fred", "Gina", "Herbert"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj



child1='B'
child2='C'
child3='D'

objold=FamilyTree('keyold')

FamilyTree.child1=child1
FamilyTree.child2=child2
FamilyTree.child3=child3


objnew=FamilyTree('keynew')

print objnew.key,objnew.child1,objnew.child2,objnew.child3
print objold.key,objold.child1,objold.child2,objold.child3
'''
keynew B C D
keyold B C D
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand this wrong, but you don't add attributes to the '**init**' method, you add attributes to the instance of the class. 'self' refers to the instance of the class.
To add attributes during runtime to a class, look at Abhra's example.
To add attributes to a specific instance of a class, look here (sorry Abhra, stole your example):

```
class FamilyTree:
    def __init__(self,rootObj):
        self.key = rootObj



child1='B'
child2='C'
child3='D'

objold=FamilyTree('keyold')

objold.child1=child1
objold.child2=child2
objold.child3=child3


objnew=FamilyTree('keynew')

print objnew.key, objnew.child1, objnew.child2, objnew.child3
print objold.key, objold.child1, objold.child2, objold.child3
'''
keynew AttributeError: 'FamilyTree' object has no attribute 'child1' (same error for the others)
keyold B C D
'''
```